# R. How to check if a dataset contains the same elements in another dataset

Tags: r

I have 2 datasets `Dataset2016_17` and `PlayOffDataset2016_17`. `Dataset2016_17$TEAM` looks like the following..

`[1] "Atlanta Hawks" "Boston Celtics" "Brooklyn Nets" etc.`

So I would like to know if values in `Dataset2016_17$TEAM` occurs in `PlayOffDataset2016_17$TEAM`. If so I want something like a table of true and false.

I have already tried something like this

```
highlight_flag <- grepl(PlayOffDataset2016_17$TEAM, Dataset2016_17$TEAM)
```

But it did not work. 
Please let me know if there are any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try out `table(unique(Dataset2016_17$TEAM) %in% unique(PlayOffDataset2016_17$TEAM))`

Comment: It gives me FALSE 14 TRUE 16. Not a table of trues and falses. Thanks for your suggestion! @ANG

Comment: You should add `unique()`. Please, note that the result is actually a table: `is.table(table(unique(df2$drat) %in% unique(df1$Sepal.Width)))`. You can store it in an object if you want: `highlight_flag <- table(unique(df2$drat) %in% unique(df1$Sepal.Width))`. If you mean a sequence of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, you can just use `unique(df2$drat) %in% unique(df1$Sepal.Width)`

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should provide sample inputs and desired output for your question. That helps us understand what you want and get you there quickly.

```
# sample data 
Dataset2016_17 = data.frame(TEAM = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
PlayOffDataset2016_17 = data.frame(TEAM = c('b', 'c', 'd'))
```

Your goal isn't super clear, you say "table", but the other answer gave you a `table` object and that wasn't what you wanted... Next time, in your question, include desired output for the sample input you give.

My best guess is that you want one of these. If you want something else, please edit your question to show what you want.

```
## teams in both
intersect(Dataset2016_17$TEAM, PlayOffDataset2016_17$TEAM)
# [1] "b" "c"

## teams in Dataset but not playoffs
setdiff(Dataset2016_17$TEAM, PlayOffDataset2016_17$TEAM)
# [1] "a"

## add a column to Dataset indicating whether the team is in the playoffs
Dataset2016_17$in_playoff = Dataset2016_17$TEAM %in% PlayOffDataset2016_17$TEAM
Dataset2016_17
#   TEAM in_playoff
# 1    a      FALSE
# 2    b       TRUE
# 3    c       TRUE
```